# After submitting node the file upload field available again Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, file-upload

I created a content type and there is a file upload field. The user uploads the file and submits the node. Then the file upload field will be available again, so the user can upload a new file.

How to implement this instead of you only see the file name and remove button?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how and studying now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload multiple files in your file field, you should make sure that the field settings allow for it.

At `Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » [Your content type] » Manage fields`, you should edit your file field. Scroll down to the **Field settings** and set the **Number of Values** to *Unlimited* if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't want to upload multiple files in the file field.  I want the form will clear the file field after submit.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  in _node_update and _node_insert delete the file field value from the database.